# how to translate char into hex and binary

Tags: c, binary, char, hex

I have the following example in C:

```
int x = 123; 

size of int = 4 bytes.
hex value = 7b
binary value = 0111 1011
```

What will be the hex/binary value if my x was a char?

```
char x = 123;
size of char = 1 byte.
hex value = ??
binary value = ??
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `char` is smaller than `int`, it would be the same. Except for leading zeros you would find in an `int`.

Try this:

```
  6   int x = 123;
  7 
  8   printf ("Size of int is  %d bytes\n", sizeof(int));
  9   printf ("Size of char is %d byte\n", sizeof(char));
 10 
 11   printf ("Hex value is %x\n", x);
 12   printf ("Hex value is %x\n", (char)x);
 13 
 14   printf ("As for binary value .... google is your friend\n");
```

Output is:

```
Size of int is  4 bytes
Size of char is 1 byte

Hex value is 7b
Hex value is 7b
```

As for binary value .... google is your friend
This [site](http://www.is.wayne.edu/olmt/binary/page3.htm) seems to explain things well

Answer (score 1):

Its hex and binary values will be exactly the same (except possibly for leading zeros if you want to expand it to the full size).

That's because 123 fits just fine into a `char`. A signed char can hold at least the values `-127` thru `127` (two's complement can handle `-128`, but the ISO standard allows for one's complement and sign/magnitude as two other encodings for negative numbers, neither of which can handle `-128`), an unsigned char at least `0` thru `255`.

Assuming an 8-bit byte and 4-byte int:

```
Value  HexInt  HexChar                 BinaryInt                 BinaryChar
-----  ------  -------  ---------------------------------------  ----------
123      7B      7B     0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0111 1011   0111 1011
```

The binary value `0111 1011` is calculated as:

```
0111 1011
 ||| | ||
 ||| | |+-   1
 ||| | +--   2
 ||| |
 ||| +----   8
 ||+------  16
 |+-------  32
 +--------  64
           ===
           123
```

If you were to attempt to place a value into an 8-bit `char` that was larger than 8 bits, the least significant bits are usually the ones preserved.

```
char xyz = 0x1234; // results in xyz being given the value 0x34.
```

This is detailed in C99, section `6.3.1.3/2` and `/3`:

> 1/ When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
>
> 2/ Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.
>
> 3/ Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I meant to use a bigger example. Where char=1234, more than 8 bits. You guys explained it. It seems the solution would be hex=0x4D2 and binary=11010001. With the first 4 bits getting dropped.

0100 1101 0001

Answer (score 0):

Decimal 123 is 0x7b in hex and 0111 1011 in binary regardless of the original type. The only times the type gets in the way is if there is overflow (eg. `int x = 48273; char y = (char)x;`). Occasionally, display of a `signed char` and an `unsigned char` may differ.

Comment: I'm getting that when I run my program.                               char x = 123;                                    printf("Before %x\n", x);  However, I would assume since char = 1 byte and 1 byte = 8 bits. char x=123; would not be 0111 1011 in binary. Since that's 8 bits.

Comment: @Gene why do you assume that ?

Answer (score 0):

It would be the same. 0x7b hex , 0111 1011

Note that if your integers are 4 bytes, its bits are 0000 0000 0111 1011 though.